# vbscript ADO Recordset Update

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to update paths in access `mdb` database using ADO and vb6 without success.

The scripts are below. The line `Rs1(columnName) = Replace( Rs1(columnName),oldPath,newPath)` causes `vbscript runtime err invalid use of Null`.

Put simply, I want to update all tables that have strings like `\\server2` to `\\DBSE-46\`. I
am running the script on win7 64bit as

```
c:\windows\syswow64\cscript.exe C:\SQLTest\HarishScripts\DatabaseAccessProg6.vbs >> C:\SQLTest\HarishScripts\DatabaseAccessProg6.txt
```

---

```
Option Explicit
WScript.Echo "START of ADO access program...."
Dim DBpath
Dim tableName
Dim columnName
Dim oldPath
Dim newPath
'@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
' Set all external variables here...
DBpath = "C:\DBTest;"
tableName = "Test"
columnName = "Path"
oldPath = "\\SERVER2\"
newPath = "\\DBSE-46\"
'@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Dim Rs1
Set Rs1 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Dim i 
Dim AccessConnect 
AccessConnect = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};" & _
                 "Dbq=MedDataSource.mdb;" & _
                 "DefaultDir=" &  DBpath & _
                 "Uid=Admin;Pwd=;"


'--------------------------
' Recordset Object Method
'--------------------------

' Recordset Open Method #4:  Open w/o Connection & w/Connect String

Dim sqlStmt
sqlStmt = "SELECT * FROM " & tableName 

' use LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic = 3. This allows update of the recordset.
Rs1.LockType = 3
Rs1.Open sqlStmt, AccessConnect


Do Until Rs1.EOF 
'WScript.Echo Rs1("Path")
if (Rs1(columnName) = NULL) Then
  End If
  Rs1(columnName) = Replace( Rs1(columnName),oldPath,newPath)
Rs1.MoveNext 
Loop 

' Close the recordset...
Rs1.Close
Set Rs1 = Nothing


WScript.Echo "..."
WScript.Echo "..."
WScript.Echo "DONE!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [IsNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbchw6hz%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function to check for Null values. In my older local .chm there is even a paragraph

> Use the IsNull function to determine whether an expression contains a
>   Null value. Expressions that you might expect to evaluate to True
>   under some circumstances, such as If Var = Null and If Var <> Null,
>   are always False. This is because any expression containing a Null is
>   itself Null, and therefore, False.

Work on your understanding of the If clause. In

```
if (Rs1(columnName) = NULL) Then
End If
Rs1(columnName) = Replace( Rs1(columnName),oldPath,newPath)
```

the last statement will be executed regardless of the content of Rs1(columnName). So do

```
if Not IsNull(Rs1(columnName)) Then
   Rs1(columnName) = Replace( Rs1(columnName),oldPath,newPath)
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Ekkehard.Horner
Your solution worked as expected on Windows XP system but comes with error "Unspecified error, line 44,1 Code 80004005, Source (null). ie "Rs1.Open sqlStmt, AccessConnect"
apparently this indicate permission error, but am running as admin and the folder permission is set to admin with full control. can you advice please?

thanks again

Comment: The error code above is because I have not install IIS on the 64bit windows 7, after enabling most of the options in ISS I was able to run the vb script using batch file or call a batch file. To install ISS to to control Panel, Program and Features turn on/off features, select IIS from list